# Where can I find a web based svn admin app that does this

Tags: svn

I am looking for a web based svn admin that can use LDAP Users and Groups which can create repos add/modify hooks of a repo through the web interface.

For example you have a LDAP group that has access to multiple repos. You can then have one user in the group that can be an admin of all users in the group.

This admin can create internal/single-repo groups for AD users and set access to repos for all users and repo groups.

Browsing the code base is not as important because there are a million tools that anyone uses for that during development.

Is there a web admin tool for svn that does all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualSVN Server is definitely the way to go. However, you can't administer permissions or hooks from the web interface. I use remote desktop to administer our install on the server. I also don't think there's any way to set admin permissions as you're asking.

Unless you have unusual needs, I advise you to keep your Subversion structure as simple as possible by using a single repository and setting permissions on folders. The [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) explains why the single repository is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The only SVN implementation that I know of that does this is VisualSVN Server.  Its free at [www.visualsvn.com](http://www.visualsvn.com)

I'm not sure if you can administer it via web; worth investigating.  But it does use Active Directory as an option for authentication and groups.